# "paralyzed because of strong emotion" Is there an idiom or fixed-phrase which conveys this meaning?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or fixed phrase meaning someone was paralyzed with the horror of a sight.

context:

- An old lady sees a young girl run over by a truck.
- A middle-aged man sees his neighbor's teenage son be struck by lightning.

Not looking for a single word (there are too many of them) and it would fit a sentence like "He/She became/was/got/etc______________________."

Comment: Stunned/stupefied or dumbstruck/dumbfounded?

Comment: @DanBron Those are not idioms.

Comment: Well, if you need an idiom, consider *deer in the headlights*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, I'm going to edit.

Comment: @DanBron  I think I would tend to call that a *metaphor* rather than an *idiom*.

Comment: "Frozen by horror" might work.

Comment: The word you may be seeking could be *transfixed*.

Comment: @WS2 Funny, over on ELL, we were just talking about how those two notions are [not mutually exclusive](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68261/is-out-of-the-blue-a-metaphor#comment130807_68261). And *transfixed* is good!

Comment: @DanBron To me an idiom is something like *please keep an eye out for John*, whilst a *metaphor* involves introducing a well-known concrete example of something as an aid to comprehension of something unconnected. But it is late at night here...

Comment: What about gobsmacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom **[stop dead in one's tracks](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+dead+in+tracks)**  seems to fit.  The *in one's tracks* refers to "on the spot" or "where one is at the moment"; it was first recorded in 1824.

*Fig. to stop completely still suddenly because of fear, a noise, etc.*
 <sub>(*McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.)*</sub>

> I ​stopped ​dead in my ​tracks when I ​heard the ​scream ([CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stop-dead-in-your-tracks))

The idiom is a variant of *[stop cold](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+cold)*, and *stop dead*.

> He was so surprised to see them in the audience that he **stopped dead** in the middle of his speech

Related to the theme of being paralysed through extreme fear are the participles ***[frozen](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frozen)*** and ***froze***, the verb is often used to express sudden shock, horror, motionless or panic at something, which renders the person affected incapable of taking appropriate action.
All the following examples are taken from *Dictionary.com*

- *I froze in my tracks*
- *The child was frozen with fear*
- *My heart froze when she told me the news*
- *Terror froze him to the steering wheel.*
- *The lifeguard should have dived in for the boy, but she froze*

Comment: Oh, nice one! This could end up being a really fun question.

Comment: I see someone has been anonymously downvoting everyone's answer.

Comment: I upvoted yours and so far it's the nearest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Centaurus what do you mean it's the nearest. Why is this "close"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA   When compared to other answers, it's the closest.  Why?  You know perfectly well what makes a good answer (definitions, references, examples, etc) and you have them all here.

Comment: @Centaurus I think she's asking why is it "close" but no cigar? Not "what makes it good" but "what prevents it from being perfect", i.e. accepted?

Comment: @DanBron "Time, gentlemen, Time."   I usually wait 48 hours before I say that. When I started here I was painfully bitten by two ladies for accepting an answer immediately.

Answer (score 4):

[**Be like a deer caught in the headlights**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+a+deer+caught+in+the+headlights) - to be so frightened or surprised that you cannot move or think.

> Each time they asked him a question he was like a deer caught in the headlights.

From [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/_/gr.aspx?url=-cambridge.org/elt/elt_projectpage.asp?id=2501153).

Answer (score 4):

To be **Petrified** is to be paralyzed or shocked into inaction by fear or horror.

"The old lady was petrified with horror at the sight of the girl going under the wheels of the truck."

Answer (score 4):

**[terror stricken](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/terror-stricken)** or **terror-struck**; *in a state of terror*

> And exactly at the moment when the space between the wheels came opposite her, she dropped the red bag, and drawing her head back into her shoulders, fell on her hands under the carriage, and lightly, as though she would rise again at once, dropped on to her knees. And at the same instant **she was terror-stricken** at what she was doing. "Where am I? What am I doing? What for?" she tried to get up, to drop backwards; but something huge and merciless struck her on the head and rolled her on her back. "Lord, forgive me all!" she said, feeling it impossible to struggle
>
> <sub>*Anna Karenina* By Tolstoy</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[**Makes the blood run cold**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+blood+run+cold) - Fig. to shock or horrify someone.

> The terrible story in the newspaper made my blood run cold. I could
>   tell you things about prisons that would make your blood run cold.

[**Scared Stiff**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scared+stiff) - Fig. badly frightened.

> We were scared stiff by the robber. I was scared stiff when the dog
>   growled at me.

Answer (score 3):

***[Scared to death](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scare+to+death)***  may suggest the idea of being  petrified by a strong emotion:

> - to make you feel extremely frightened, scare the hell out of you. *David suddenly appeared like a ghost in the doorway and scared me to death.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)